# How are empty text-nodes processed?

Tags: xml, xslt, textnode

If i apply the following xslt

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b/*">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">text</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

on the following xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<a>
   <b></b>
</a>
```

the output is

```xml
<a>
    text
    <b></b>
    text
</a>
```

What i don't get: All the empty text-nodes between the elements get processed except the empty text-node inside the element b. I don't see any difference on how the child elements of a and b are processed.

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty text node. A text node always has at least one character of data.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, that is not true, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-text: "An `xsl:text` element may be empty, in which case the result of evaluating the instruction is a text node whose string value is the zero-length string". So at least constructing empty text nodes is possible.

Comment: @MartinHonnen The above is a verbatim quote from the XPath 1.0 specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no empty text node inside the `b` element, it is an empty element that has no child nodes at all. On the other hand, the `a` element has three child nodes, the first is a text node with whitespace (at least a line break and some space or tab characters), the second is the `b` element, the third is a text node with white space (at least a line break).

Also where did you get that result with the indentation of the `text` output you have shown? At http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/94hvTyG I get the output `<a>text<b></b>text</a>`

Comment: Thats one of the information i did not find at all. I thought that <b></b> (no space) and <b>   </b> (space) are equivalent. Its not really obvious. For example an empty string in java exists, no matter if its empty or not. But thank you.

I formatted the output for the better reading. There were no linebreaks.

Comment: No, `<b></b>` and `<b> </b>` are not equivalent, unless you also use `xsl:strip-space`. As for the Java comparison, I am not sure I understand it, but if you look at various object models in Java to represent XML trees (e.g. W3C DOM, JDOM, XOM) then I am sure they will have an empty collection of child nodes for the `<b></b>` element, which of course doesn't mean you cannot, on the other hand, compute the "string value" of that element and get an empty string, e.g. in the W3C DOM Level 3 `getTextContent()` would give you an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, at least in the XSLT 2.0/3.0 model, a zero-length text node can exist, but only if it is parentless; as soon as you try and attach it to a parent element, it disappears. So if you do:

```
<xsl:variable name="x" as="node()">
  <xsl:text/>
</xsl:variable>
```

then `count($x)` returns 1, `$x instance of text()` returns true, and `string-length($x)` returns 0. But when you do

```
<xsl:variable name="e" as="node()">
   <xsl:copy-of select="$x"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

then `count($x)/child::node()` returns 0. This is defined by the rules for Constructing Complex Content (§5.7.1 in XSLT 3.0, rule 6) "Zero-length text nodes within the sequence are removed."

And the XDM data model defines a constraint (§6.7.1 rule 1 in the 3.1 version): "If the parent of a text node is not empty, the Text Node must not contain the zero-length string as its content."

Note that the W3C specs consistently use the word "empty" to refer to a set that has no members, while a string that has no characters is always called "zero-length". In my example above, $x is zero-length but it is not empty.

The situation in XPath 1.0 / XSLT 1.0 is different. Parentless text nodes cannot arise in 1.0, therefore zero-length text nodes cannot ever exist.